# Google maps api v3 LatLng conversion error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing a ajax call to request a position and move a marker relative to what the position is. The problem is that the LatLng command simply returns (NaN,NaN) even though the variable "data" actually contains a position. what am i doing wrong here?

```
  function marker()
  {
        $.get("ajax.php", { do: "getpos" }, function(data){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data);
                alert(latlng);
            beachMarker.setPosition(latlng);
        });
        //setTimeout( "marker()", 10000);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a link to all your code or put it in a jsFiddle or something so we can see all of it at once? That way we can test it out as it's running.

Comment: Any clues as to what the data variable is or where it is coming from?

Comment: Seems to me that your data variable contains a single value or an array.  But the LatLng class takes two arguments (neither a single value nor an array).  If it's an array, then you need to reference the array elements (i.e., `(data[0], data[1])`).

Answer (score 1):

As [Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) says, `LatLng` constructor should have 2 parameters, both must be numbers. Your ajax response can't be of number type. It is probably string, which you should split and parse to numbers for passing to `LatLng` constructor.